# Is there a way to programmatically create an Azure ServiceBus Topic

Tags: azure, servicebus

I am trying to create a `Topic` in `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` via code. I see there was a `NamespaceManager` object in `Microsoft.ServiceBus`, but I can't find anything for the newer `Azure` namespace. I am using .NET Core.

Has this yet to be implemented? Or did I just not look hard enough?

If this isn't possible, is there a way to create a filter on `SubscriptionClient()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They changed it all around in .NET Standard. You should be able to do this using the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus` nuget library. More info found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65).

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management) for CRUD operations on ServiceBus resources.